# duplicity states first hostname letter is uppercase

Tags: hostname, duplicity

Can anyone guess, why duplicity suddenly started to make or treat the first hostname letter uppercase?

```
[root@crew shared_scripts]# duplicity --version
duplicity 0.7.10

[root@crew shared_scripts]# uname -a
Linux crew.gdndev.xyz 3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 18 19:05:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@crew shared_scripts]# echo $HOSTNAME 
crew.gdndev.xyz

[root@crew shared_scripts]# hostname
crew.gdndev.xyz

[root@crew shared_scripts]# duplicity --archive-dir /archive-dir --name backup-name --no-encryption --full-if-older-than 2W /backup-source scp://backup-destination
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Tue Nov  8 00:16:35 2016
Fatal Error: Backup source host has changed.
Current hostname: Crew.gdndev.xyz
Previous hostname: crew.gdndev.xyz
```

It was OK yesterday... No package updates for over a week. Uptime 6 days.

What are other ways to get hostname, some other source? Something which could be altered and not affect $(hostname)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this duplicity bug ticket holds some hints
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/662334

easiest would be to use the appropriate cmd line switch '--allow-source-mismatch' one time to assure duplicity that you are on the same machine still.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Aha! It's not duplicity!
>>> import socket; socket.getfqdn()
'Crew.gdndev.jeppesen.com'